# Creating a timer for a javascript game gives undesirable results

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, timer

I am designing a game in HTML5 with Canvas/JavaScript.
    My aim is to create a timer that will countdown from a certain amount of minutes down to zero, during the time you need to shoot as many enemies as you can. I have been busy searching for effective timers but some implementations caused issues which crashed the browser (probably infinite loop) or the countdown of  (timeInSeconds ) goes down way to fast.

this is the code i most recently implemented to try to get it to work

```
function setTimerCountdown(){
timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - 1;
    ctx.fillText(timeInSeconds, 200,180);
}
```

I have already got a setInterval which is used to update the game
here is the code for that, this code lies at the bottom of the js file

```
var main = function () {

var now = Date.now();
var delta = now - then;
update(delta / 1000);
render();
then = now;
};

// Let's play this game!
reset();
var then = Date.now();
var fps = 60;
setInterval(main, 1000/fps); // Execute as fast as possible
```

i then have additional code such as the render function, which renders the pictures to the screen and the text, here is the code for this

```
var render = function () {

returnKillsNeeded(stageNum);
            ctx.drawImage(startGameImg, 0,0);
            ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = "top";
            ctx.fillText("press Enter to start", 250, 300);
            ctx.fill();
    if(gameStart){
if (bgReady) {
ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);


}
setInterval(setTimerCountdown, 1000);
setTimeOut(setTimerCountdown, 1000);
ctx.fillStyle="#522900";
ctx.fillRect(0,480,500,120);
```

the idea is to countdown the time from 120 ( i do know that there is no catch available to stop time going in to negative values, as well as unnecessary code namely currentTime and time.
As mentioned several attempts of implementation had proven unsuccessful,

My questions are, should i have the setInterval or setTimeOut or any aspect of a timer in the render method?, is the code mentioned quoted above the same code i should use to create the timer?. I know that there is quite a few examples out there but i can't seem to break into how i can apply that code into mine without screwing up all the work i've done so far. I had links attached i was willing to use to show you my research but due to frustrating (fix your code structure) popups on this site i had excluded links to a video from a youtube channel called goTreeHouse - create a timer in javascript and several stack questions already asked.

To add further possibly relavant info. I am not using any API's (JQuery etc). just HTML5, CSS, JavaScript (using notepad++).

Assistance is appreciated, also point out any faults in the code, that you currently see. Also i suppose another thing div tags, only 1 being used is a div tag for the canvas, all the text, images and music is through js, once again without additional API's

edit:
below is the code with the edit, also note the if statement block in the render function, this is to stop the minus figures from showing up on screen (it does not however take into account that in the background the function is still updating and the negative value is getting bigger, i will look into addressing this problem.

```
//Thanks to GameAlchemist
function createCountDown(timeRemaining) {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    return function() {
    return timeRemaining - ( Date.now() - startTime );
    }
}
var currentCountDown = createCountDown(30000);

// Draw everything
var render = function () {



var countDownValue = currentCountDown();

returnKillsNeeded(stageNum);
            ctx.drawImage(startGameImg, 0,0);
            ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = "top";
            ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
            ctx.fillText("press Enter to play", 250, 450);
            ctx.fill();
    if(gameStart){
if (bgReady) {
ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);


}

ctx.fillStyle="#522900";
ctx.fillRect(0,480,500,120);
ctx.drawImage(scoreImg, 22,522);
ctx.drawImage(livesImg, 360,522);

ctx.drawImage(progressImg, 200,492);
createProgressBar();
createProgressPercent();
ctx.fillText("progress", 170,492);
setEnemyHealthText();
drawPlayer();
if(countDownValue <=0){
    countDownValue = 0;
    }else{
ctx.fillText(countDownValue, 200,190);
}
```

Comment: get Date.now() at the start, and then on the update take away the start date from a new Date.now(). this will give you the time progressed since start, and if you take that value away from the amount of time you want them to have, for example 1 minute (60000) and then when that value is below 0, time is up!

Comment: If you're going to be writing lots of javascript look at http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/. Also check out talk by Douglas Crockford. These types of resources will help you prevent a lot of gotchas.

Comment: Beagle, thats useful admittedly i have been struggling to understand why  var data=function is used as opposed to function name, since i only started learning js recently, from learning java. Rory when you say get Date.now() at the start, do you start of the script, start of the game loop or the function?

Comment: You could have a global variable named `timer` or whatever with initial value of 0, and just keep on adding the `delta` value you already have on your `main` function to it. You then could check it inside of the `update` method, like `if(timer >= 120000){...do things... reset timer to 0`

Comment: Here, it's counting 10 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/KuuMt/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a closure, you can have a countdown in a few lines of codes.
Since i guess you'll need more than one countdown (one for each stage), here's a function that returns a countdown function :

```
function createCountDown(timeRemaining) {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    return function() {
       return timeRemaining - ( Date.now() - startTime );
    }
}
```

that's it !

now to use it, do :

```
// creating a coundown, at stage start
var currentCountDown = createCountDown(30000); // 30 seconds countdown

//... during the game, just use with :
var countDownValue = currentCountDown();     // in ms
```